# CSS No margin after every 5th image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a section with 2 divs with the following classes assigned to them.  In the colorbook images DIV I am displaying images one after another (there's different numbers of images depending on filters being set).  All the images are the same size so 5 will fit on a line and then wrap to the next line.  After each image, as you can see, I have a right margin of 20px.  However, I would like there NOT to be a right margin after each 5th image.  The idea is to have the images fill the entire width of the DIV they are in.

Section DIV

```
.l-colorbook-detail {
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 75.5em;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

colorbook images div

```
.colorbook-images {
  width: 80.0%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.0%;
  border:thin ;
  border-color: #CC0033 ;
  border-style:double;  
}
.l-colorbook-detail:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

2nd DIV for navigation

```
.colorbook-filters {
  width: 18.0%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  border:thin ;
  border-color:#0033FF ;
  border-style:double;
}
```

And finally the CSS for the images themselves.

```
.colorbook-color-guide__color-option {
  width: 172px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `.colorbook-color-guide__color-option:nth-child(5n) { margin-right: 0 }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override on cascade the `margin-right` every 5 images through `:nth-child` pseudoclass

```
.colorbook-images img:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

or you may just set a `margin-right` to every image except `:nth-child(5n)` (chaining a `:not` pseudoclass)

```
.colorbook-images img:not:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not clear from OP question, but I think the `nth-child` should be on the colorbook and not the `img` since the margin is defined in the parent of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth-of-type pseudo selector to do this.

```
image.nth-of-type(5){
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

This is better than using nth-child as suggested in other answers so that you could add a caption, etc without having to change it.